# Opensource PHP reporting tool

Tags: open-source, php, mysql, reporting

We are using an application developed by our internal team from last 2 years. It is ERP like application. Now the data is increased to such extent that we can't figure out the **analytics from data**. So to make the **reports and analytics** which is the best **PHP Reporting Tool.**

I have tried Jasper Reports but it is best for JAVA.

My data is stored in MySQL
And my application is in CakePHP.

Comment: You have to give us more details, so that we can help you. What kind of database is the data stored in? Why do you want the reporting tool to be in PHP? Even if your ERP is in PHP, your reporting tool could be in Java. By the way, what kind of reporting would you like to do? (give us a few examples). Thanks, and welcome to Software Recommendations! :-)

Comment: I am using MySQL for storing data. I want to get the analytics from ERP for e.g. there is leave management module so I want to check which employee is taking more leave . what is the frequency of leaves with graphs and report. And many other modules are there with alot of data.

Comment: The reporting tool would probably connect to MySQL directly, without caring about the PHP code. Is it OK? Do you want the reports and analytics to be done from within the ERP application maybe? (harder to do, requires development)

Comment: Yes it is. Then which is best tool?

Comment: I personally love Pentaho and Jasper. It is hard to tell which one would be the best for you, because the question does not mention many requirements... Actually the question really becomes "What is the best reporting tool that can read from an ERP's custom MySQL tables and generate reports/analytics?" ... which is quite a broad question. Let me think a bit.

Comment: By the way, is Open Source a requirement?

Comment: Yes I need open source only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jasper Reports on PHP using [this implementation of Jasper Report on PHP](http://www.simitgroup.com/?q=PHPJasperXML), it's quite good, but i think is not 100% compatible, anyway you get most of the features of Jasper Report natively on PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Pentaho Community](http://community.pentaho.com/), it's a very good product for Business Analysis. The community edition contains the **Report Designer** module that can connect to any input source (Text file, CSV file, DB Server, Sqlite, etc etc) through the **Data Integration** module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently looking myself but have found a fairly extensive list.

Most I am ignoring because they seem to be relatively old or under powered but here are a few more that haven't been mentioned previously:

- [Reportico](http://www.reportico.org/site/index.php)
- [Php Reports](http://jdorn.github.io/php-reports/)
- [DMYReports](http://dmyreports.sourceforge.net/)

Hope that helps (btw, I'm leaning toward Reportico or Pentaho Community... depending on which one is easier to setup).